# How to serve a html page from a subdirectory?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to serve a HTML page from a subdirectory (not the 'static' one, via YAML, not the 'template' one, via Django or Jinja)

How can I reference the path + file name in the `self.response.out.write`(?) statement?

Comment: Why don't you want to use 'template'. Is it because your HTML file is static?

Comment: And if it's static, why don't you want to serve it via the static handler?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I undersood, but I feel like you want to consider HTML files without template.

If so, you may want to try this solution...

You can define the path as follows:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'your_directory/your_html.html')
```

Then, you can print the content of your HTML like this:

```
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, 0))
```